# Making bash script with command already containing '$1'

Tags: bash

Somewhere I found this command that sorts lines in an input file by number of characters(1st order) and alphabetically (2nd order):

```
while read -r l; do echo "${#l} $l"; done < input.txt | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2- > output.txt
```

It works fine but I would like to use the command in a bash script where the name of the file to be sorted is an argument:

```
& cat numbersort.sh
#!/bin/sh
while read -r l; do echo "${#l} $l"; done < $1 | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2- > sorted-$1
```

Entering `numbersort.sh input-txt` doesn't give the desired result, probably because $1 is already in using as an argument for something else.

How do I make the command work in a shell script?

Comment: Are you sure you want `/bin/sh` and not `/bin/bash`?

Comment: "Doesn't give the desired result"? How exactly does it differ from the desired result?

Comment: Also, "command already containing `$1`"? Huh? The original command contains a `$l`, not a `$1`. As such, are you sure this question isn't simply a result of a typo?

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with your original script when used with simple arguments that don't involve quoting issues. That said, there are a few bugs addressed in the below version:

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf '%d %s\n' "${#line}" "$line"
done <"$1" | sort -n | cut -d " " -f 2- >"sorted-$1"
```

- Use `#!/bin/bash` if your goal is to write a bash script; `#!/bin/sh` is the shebang for POSIX sh scripts, not bash.
- Clear IFS to avoid pruning leading and trailing whitespace from input and output lines
- Use `printf` rather than `echo` to avoid ambiguities in the POSIX standard (see http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/utilities/echo.html, particularly APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).
- Quote expansions (`"$1"` rather than `$1`) to prevent them from being word-split or glob-expanded

Note also that this creates a new file rather than operating in-place. If you want something that operates in-place, tack a `&& mv -- "sorted-$1" "$1"` on the end.